How deeply does yakisugi protect the wood?
I want to make a cutting board out of ash and I want to char the outside using Yakisugi, because I love that black color.
A cutting board has to be smooth and hard, so I would need to scrape off the char very thoroughly and then plane it. I've seen people doing this online, but I'm not sure that it's possible to plane off enough material to be flat without taking off all the color and the protective layer.
For these reasons, is it really possible to use this technique for something like a cutting board?

First off congrats on not calling this shou sugi ban. The real question here is how deeply does the black colouration go, since that's what you actually want. While it's tempting to say it depends on how deeply the charring/heat modification is taken the basic answer is likely to be not deeply enough. I'm fairly certain based on burnt/charred hardwood that I've recovered that this won't be possible because once you plane deeply enough below the charring the wood won't be black (in fact in some areas it may be close to the original ash colour) and cos the technique works best in softer species.

This suggests switching gears and looking at other ways of making the wood black, which of course includes the iron acetate method. [While ash is not naturally a good candidate for this, when you rely on an exterior source of tannin for depth of colour and uniformity then it really doesn't matter if the wood has much tannin in it naturally.] But closer to what you asked about, do you know of the hot-iron scorching process using with paulownia? Again I don't think it'll work well with ash because it's hard and dense, but worth trying. Maybe just go straight to using aniline dye? :-)

i.e., whatever you do, try it on a small sample piece first! ;)

@Graphus What you say makes sense to me. I've watched videos of people burning the wood and then planing down so that there's no more black, and wondering how that could possibly be keeping any of the benefit of the burning.

"I've watched videos of people burning the wood and then planing down so that there's no more black, and wondering how that could possibly be keeping any of the benefit of the burning" I would think it would keep about as much as anyone'd guess, which is very little to none at all! As you I'm sure have seen in videos of it used in its conventional way, while they're conscientious about removing the char, in general you are still left with wood that's *very* dark at least, if not still basically fully black. It's the carbonised surface and the thermally modified wood beneath that are [contd]

...resistant to UV-propagated decay and fungal or insect attack (both?) so it can't be the case that removing all the obviously modified wood leaves you with anything much at all. If not actually nothing of significance.

So anyway, is the idea behind this project to use ash and see how much the method can improve its resistance? Or is it primarily about getting a black board at the end of the day? If it is just the former, you don't actually have to use a naturally rot-resistant species for cutting boards (and hence don't need to worry about modifying woods that aren't). Ash has a terrible reputation for its exterior durability as I guess you know, but that's a very different set of circumstances to what a cutting board has to withstand, even in a household that would be washing it very regularly, even daily.

I didn't know that about ash, actually, so thanks for that information. Most of it was about getting a black color without using any dubious chemicals, but some of it was just because I find this technique fascinating.

If you're looking for black, India ink seems to be popular. If you like the technique, then it sounds like it's time to experiment & practice.

@FreeMan Is India Ink suitable for a cutting board, i.e. non-toxic?

According to this "India ink is a type of carbon black pigment. It’s from soot that’s collected from burning oil, tar, or other materials. The soot is then mixed with water and a binding agent to create the ink... it’s waterproof and doesn’t fade over time." and "It can also appear in tattooing, printing, and creating designs on the skin. It’s safe for use on the skin and won’t cause any irritation". So definitely maybe! :D More searching would be necessary.

At the base, it's just the same soot you're creating by burning the wood in the first place. The question is the "binding agent". A search for "india ink toxic" gave "non-toxic india ink" prompts, so it appears that there are some binding agents that are and some that aren't.

Oh, interesting. That makes sense. So now I'm curious about how you could make your own, and know exactly what's in it.

Hmm, from that article: "India ink is not waterproof". So that'd make it not good for a cutting board, although I assume this depends on the binder.
